# (directory-files) returns nil unexpectedly 

Tags: emacs, elisp

The directory I keep my important files is stored as a string "/home/wdkrnls/Org/" in the variable `org-dir`.

I want to list all the files in `org-dir` that aren't backup files or org files (ie. that match `^[a-z0-9]+\.org$`).  So I typed the following into *Scratch*:

```
;; (directory-files DIRECTORY &optional FULL MATCH NOSORT)    
(directory-files    org-dir             '()  "^[a-z0-9]+\.org$")
```

But this returns `nil`.  Even though `ls` in /eshell/ gives me:

```
Notes.org  Store  Tasks.org
```

Can you explain why mine doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your regexp, you want:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.org$"
```

You forgot the capitalized version of `A-Z`.  And, you want a double `\` so that the string reading leaves a `\` in place to make the regexp treat the `.` as a `.`.